# How to implement DatePicker dialog within SharedPreference and error handle?

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I have used the code below to create a datepicker dialog when the user clicks on the edit text, i have tired to save the date as a string within shared preference and load it as a string, however when the user closes and opens the application again i receive an error regarding nullObject reference, how can i error handle this?

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    updateLabel();
}

};

   edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new DatePickerDialog(classname.this, date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
});

  private void updateLabel() {

String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

edittext.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

i have tired the code to error handle but it does not work:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edittext.getText().toString())) {
                edittext.setError("Please select Date");
            }
```

to save the date i have used the code:

```
String currentDate = sdf.format(DCal.getTime());
SharedPreferences Dsave = getSharedPreferences(DateSave, this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Dsave.edit();

        editor.putString("Date", currentDate);
editor.apply();
```

and to load i have used:

```
 SharedPreferences Dload = getSharedPreferences(DateSave, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
St_Date = Load.getString("Date", "");

edittext.setText(St_Date);
```

Comment: What are the error logs you get?

Comment: cannot invoke method on nullobject, i know its because when the data is loaded into the edittext the date picker is null but the edittext is not, how can i create a error handling method that can detect the empty datepicker?

Comment: For your future questions, please always include `error logs` from `logcat` to question as it is useful to understand the problem correctly. With the information you have given now, nobody can tell anything that will solve your problem quickly. I think this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/6272369

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: no because i understand what the issue is however i do not know how to error handle the datepicker dialog if the object is null